# Windows 11 keeps redoing intallation steps on VMware

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, windows, vmware

I have a Macbook pro 2019 with Intel core i7.
I have successfully installed Linux using VMware. The location of that VM is on a LaCie hard drive. I'm now trying to install Windows 11. I have done it with the ISO on their website, and it does all the installation steps alright then I get a message that says "The PC will now restart before pursuing" and when restarting, it's like I have to do all the installation steps again. Linux runs fine and all my files are still okay everytime I boot it, but it's like Windows was never installed when it boots back up.

Also I have too boot it on the hard drive because my Mac is almost at full capacity. Need all this for school.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When it offers to restart, first disconnect the ISO.  It sounds like you're repeatedly booting from the disc rather than from the installed OS.

Comment: I downloaded the Win11_22H2_English_x64v2.iso file from Microsoft and installed Windows 11 Pro in a VMware Fusion Player (version 12.1.2) virtual machine without encountering the problem described the question. I have Catalina installed on an external USB SSD as the host OS on a 2013 iMac. I was able to install and use VMware Fusion Player for free after getting a free [Personal Use License](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/en/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal-13).